# Battery power for NStimer

Tags: iphone, ipad, nstimer

will creduce Battery Power?suppose If I use lot of timers in My App 
for Animation, will it affect My Battery Power?

Answer (score 2):

The timer itself does not consume any (or almost any) power but animations requires gpu/cpu power of course.